# IE doesn't load more than 30 stylesheets (drupal)?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drupal

I have a page that calls about 32 stylesheets. On another page, it calls < 30. In every other browser both pages look fine, but on the first page in IE (8, 7), the last 2 stylesheets aren't being called and it totally messes up the layout. I'm not really sure how to get around this in drupal.

EDIT:
Also, I understand that having more than 30 is not that great, but that is how our site was developed originally. We have a bunch of themes and modules that add syleshets using "drupal_add_css".

I tried compressing the css by going to admin/settings/performance but the stylesheet link doesn't work because we are using a port number for our test site (http://mysite:123) and the link generated is http://mysite/public/css/random_string.css

Comment: "I have a page that calls about 32 stylesheets." = that's the main problem. You really should have 1 stylesheet.

Comment: While I agree, this is a site that was handed to me to work on, it has a bunch of modules and themes working together.

Comment: The limit is 31 actually.  IE10 increases this limit to 65534.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx

Comment: I agree that it would be nice to have < 32 stylesheets--but that's how Drupal works.  It's not really under AllisonC's control.  There are trade-offs for the flexibility Drupal provides and this is one.

Comment: @DA, That's a rather unhelpful comment. Some people don't re-run their JS/CSS minimizer/compressor after every edit when developing. This is yet another reason to hate IE.

Comment: @Cerin if someone doesn't realize 32 stylesheets is bad, it's a very helpful comment. I, of course, also realize that sometimes that's out of our control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use admin/settings/performance and set Optimize CSS to true.  This will put out 1 css instead of 32+.  If you are developing and want this on to work in IE, you need to clear the cache after changing your css.  We tend to leave this off in development & only turn it on to test in IE or for production.

All best,
ember

---

Answer to Alison's comment (too long for a comment block)

Hi AlisonC,

I've never tried using a port for a site with Drupal.  I'd suggest making sure your settings.php for your site are setup correctly.  There may need to be a special name for your folder (see the instructions at the top of settings.php) or you may need to check the $base_url and make sure it has the port.

If that doesn't work, there's a module for caching css while developing (http://drupal.org/project/ie_css_optimizer).  I haven't used it, but it may work a little differently at least for your situation. (After typing this I noticed another user also recommended it).

I've been assuming you're still developing, and I would remove the ie css optimizer module (or at least turn it off) before going live, since it's primarily a developer helper.  I think this is the limit of my knowledge.  Good luck!

--Ember

Comment: When we do that, the stylsheet link that now appears isn't valid. When I try to go to it, it says page not found.

Comment: Hi AlisonC, Have you cleared your Drupal cache after changing the setting?  Also, clear your IE cache just in case it's holding onto something for the url.  We don't usually use ports for sites, we just use test domain names, so I'm not sure how the port number might interfere.  --ember

Comment: It's not that it's caching it, the link it is providing to the stylesheet doesn't include the port number, so it wont load it.

Comment: I modified includes/common.inc to change the port number. Now it is compressing the css and everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known limitation with IE - you cannot have more than 31 stylesheets on any given page.

References:

- http://john.albin.net/css/ie-stylesheets-not-loading
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ad1b6e88-bbfa-4cc4-9e95-3889b82a7c1d/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx

The only real solution you have is to combine your stylesheets so you have fewer individual CSS files (use Drupal's "Optimize CSS" option). But I acknowledge this may be a pain if you're trying to debug your code, etc.

In fact, it is *possible* to load a lot more than 31 stylesheets into IE, but for any more than 31, you need to do it via an `@import` line inside another CSS file. This isn't really possible in the context of a Drupal site, where each stylesheet is added by a module, and you don't really have control of how Drupal adds them to the page.

Answer (score 0):

How are they being loaded? 30 individual `<link href="blahblah.css">` calls? Or from other stylesheets with `@import` directives? Remember that if there's a syntax error, further processing of a stylesheet will fail.

Comment: They are loaded using < link href syntax... loaded through drupal using drupal_add_css

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/ie_css_optimizer
...is what we use. Theme debugging is a pain with CSS optimization turned on. D7 uses the @import method this module implements to get around the issue.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a module to deal with this.  I haven't used it personally but it does have 5K+ users (Drupal 6).